# App is not connecting to the mongodb Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I start learning JavaScript on the freecodecamp and stuck on a challenge.

The challenge itself is to setup a mongoose.
But every time I am submitting my answer it giving me an error of "mongoose should be connected to a database.

I checked the fcc forum on the same topic and all of the solutions not working for me

The challenge provide the starting code and all what is required is to setup mongo atlas and connect your app to it

In the app.js you should add

```js
    require("dotenv").config();
    let mongoose = require("mongoose");

    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true
    });
```

in the .env file
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://userName:password@cluster0.rmycu.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase

Where the `userName` and `password` are changed to mine without any prohibited symbols.

You should also add this dependencies to `package.json`

```json
    "mongodb": "4.1.1",
    "mongoose": "6.0.5"
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: have you created database `myFirstDatabase` in atlas ?

Comment: You can solve this creating a new database user access in the security tab of mongodb atlas.

Comment: I hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks Gulshan, tried to create new user, sadly seems nothing is changing. Still getting the same error

Comment: I didn't create the myFirstDatabase, cause its not been written in the challenge

Comment: UPDATE: creating database did not solve the problem. Furthermore when i tried to pass this challenge before on replit everything worked fine with the code i mentioned above, but now its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change connection config and use it without additional options:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
```

Since you are using Mongoose version higher than 6.0, these options are not available as config anymore, and are configured automatically.